# What's the `feed data` and `store data` for database?

Tags: database, rrdtool, rrd

Is there difference between `feed data` and `store data`?

I am watching the [Tutorial](https://youtu.be/JaK-IctEyWs) in the `9:00` moment.

It introduce the rrdtool, there are `feed data` and `store data` nouns. I want to know whether the feed data is provide to the RRD, and store data will only store the data into the database?

What's the `feed data` meaning?

Comment: Without watching the tutorial - are you sure they are not talking about entities from the problem domain?

Comment: He is talking about the RRD.

Comment: Appologies - should have looked more closely!